# Filtering a gallery in PowerApps with entities from CDS

Tags: powerapps, cds

I have a gallery in a canvas app that I want to filter with a field from an entity in CDS. My entity name is 'Quality Alerts', I'm trying to lookup the field 'Assigned To' and filter the gallery to show only records with the 'Assigned To' value that equals a label I have set off to the side of the gallery.

I have a label that shows the users name that I wish to filter the gallery with. However I have yet to find a way to successfully lookup that name through the field in the entity called 'Assigned To'. I've tried using functions like `exactin` or `in` to filter like I normally would with an excel sheet as a data source but no luck.

```
Filter('Quality Alerts', Label62.Text = 'Assigned To')
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have several different instances I need to filter similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and changed the field name to Assigned that way I get rid of the space and changed the code to this,
        `Filter('Quality Alerts DBS', Assigned = Label62.Text)`
This gave me the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a `Lower()` method to ensure you're looking at the same text.

```
Filter( 'Quality Alerts', Lower(Label62.Text) in Lower('Assigned To') )
```

Barring that you could try a `StartsWith()`

```
Filter( 'Quality Alerts', StartsWith( 'Assigned To', Label62.Text ) )
```

Just in case - here is the full documentation around this topic. [Functions: Filter - Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)

Comment: So far for both of those I get: Invalid argument types(OptionSetValue). Expecting a Text value instead.

Comment: Try adding .Value at the end.  It looks like you're trying to compare the value of a CDS OptionSet to Text.